# Create custom model structure similar to django model in python?

Tags: python, django

I am working in Python 2.7 and trying to create a model structure which is something similar to django models **but without database**. Consider the following situation:
I want to create a model for Products (e.g CarryBag) which will have some predefined attributes of basic type (string, int, boolean etc), using which instances can be created. This model must inherit from an abstract model say 'GenericProduct' which will have certain defined functionality related to a product:

```
class GenericProduct:
    name = StringType(required=True)
    id = StringType(required=True)

    def to_json(self):
        ....
    def to_xml(self):
        ...
    def some_other_function(self):
        ...

class CarryBag(GenericProduct):
    material = StringType(required=True, default="Polyester", help_text="Type of material used")
    price = IntType(required=True)        
    available = BooleanType(default=False)
```

So, challenges are:

- This modelling structure must work very much similar to Django models but without database interaction.
- How do I define abstract class 'GenericProduct'
- How do I create a class that defines datatype classes 'IntType', 'StringType' & 'BooleanType' which can be used to define attributes.

What is the best way to achieve this keeping in mind python constructs. I am trying to go through django db model code to get some sense about it. Following is my code for one of the datatype classes:

```
class StringType(object):
def __init__(self, default=None, required=False, help_text=None):
    self.required = required
    self.help_text = help_text

    if default:
        self.__set__(self,default)

def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    return self.value

def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        raise TypeError("'{}' must be a string.".format(value))
    self.value = value
```

And this is how I was using it:

```
class GenericProduct:
    name = StringType(required=True) # WRONG: This creates a static member of the class
    .....
```

Comment: How do you intend to use it? I mean you are saying 'structure like django models without database'. Exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Rajesh,
I found a link [jsonobject](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonobject/), this is exactly I was trying to achieve. Notice how it allows you to create classes with 'Property' instance variables. I guess I will use this library, tune it to according to my needs.

Comment: Have a look at Abstract Base Classes in python, it should give you base of how to create your abstract base class, which you can then inherit